# Vdbench 50404rc2 beta code - sparse file creation

Tags: sparse-file

Can anyone please let me know any pointers to create Sparse files(holey files) in latest vdbench 50404rc2. It seems that this is the latest supported feature.

Link for more info:
https://community.oracle.com/thread/3759500?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

The answer was given by Henk, but on oracle vdbench forum so posting the excerpt from it,also the below link to forum post.

> This is EXPERIMENTAL, so it will work for now, but once I get feedback and decide that this experiment was successful I will change the instructions to activate it.
>   That means that the '-d86' info below will no longer work.
>   To activate truncate, add '-d86' as an execution parameter, or, add 'debug=86' at the top of your parameter file.
>   (For experiments adding an other 'debug=' parameter is much easier than fiddling with the Vdbench parameter parser. If I decide to make this permanently available I'll worry about adding a more 'official' parameter.)
>   This uses the Unix 'ftruncate()' and similar Windows function during file creation.
>   This will create ONLY sparse files during the format, not one block of data is written until further Vdbench workloads are run against these files.

The definition file.

debug=86
fsd=fsd1,anchor=/tmp/sparsedir,depth=1,width=1,files=10,size=40k
fwd=fwd1,fsd=fsd1,operation=read,xfersize=4k,fileio=sequential,fileselect=random,threads=1
rd=rd1,fwd=fwd1,fwdrate=max,format=yes,elapsed=10,interval=1